# Invoke-Command invocation of server script error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have this script in the client computer that try to run a script from the server computer:

```
try {
      $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "name" -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $credential
      Enter-PSSession -Id $s.Id
      Set-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope CurrentUser
      Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath c:\release1.ps1
} catch {
      Write-Error "Error occurred: " $_.Exception.ToString()
} finally {
      Exit-PSSession
      Remove-PSSession $s }
```

the script in the server is something like this

`Set-Alias vmrun "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"`
`Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath vmrun -ArgumentList " -T ws revertToSnapshot M:\myvm.vmx Release1"`

but I got the error

> Write-Error : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException: Cannot
>    find path 'C:\release1.ps1' because it does not exist.

Comment: `-FilePath` must specify a path to a file *on the local computer*.  Is `C:\release1.ps1` on the local computer or the remote one?

Comment: the file is in the remote computer

Comment: Note that `Enter-PSSession -Id $s.Id` enters an _interactive session_ that the user must explicitly exit. Therefore, all subsequent commands (a) don't execute until that has happened and (b) then execute _locally_.

Answer (score 2):

`-FilePath` must specify a path to a file *on the local computer*.  The file is read locally, then passed to the remote computer as a block of code.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx:

> Runs the specified local script on one or more remote computers. Enter the path and file name of the script, or pipe a script path to Invoke-Command. **The script must reside on the local computer or in a directory that the local computer can access.** Use the ArgumentList parameter to specify the values of parameters in the script.

The solution is to put `release1.ps1` on the local computer.  Or if it must be on the remote computer, then put it in a share that is accessible to the local computer and access it with a UNC path.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath \\name\share\release1.ps1
```