# Why can't I execute remote scripts using powershell (5.1)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have two computers on the same domain. winrm is running on both machines. Test-WSMan is running on the remote machine. I can execute `invoke-command -scriptblock {dir c:\automatedtests} -computername RemoteComputername` and it returns the expected result:

```
Directory: C:\automatedtests


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                PSComputerName

d-----        1/11/2022   5:45 PM                ErrorLog.txt                        us14-pacci04
a-----        1/13/2022  12:16 PM             18 test.ps1                            us14-pacci04
```

. But if I try to execute a script on that same machine (`invoke-command -computername 'RemoteComputerName' -filepath 'C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1'`) I get the error:

```
invoke-command : Cannot find path 'C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-command -session $s -filepath {C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1:String) [Invoke-Command], ItemNotFoundExcepion
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I have been googling this for days with no solution. What am I missing? It's got to be something simple that I'm missing.

Edit 1/18/22 1:18pm PT: OK - I understand now that -filepath refers to a local file. So the only way to run a script on a remote computer (with the script stored there) is to use the share?

Comment: The `-FilePath` parameter is looking for that file on your localhost. _"Specifies a local script that this cmdlet runs on one or more remote computers."_

Comment: Does `C:\AutomatedTest\test.ps1` exist locally?  The `-FilePath` parameter "Specifies a local script that this cmdlet runs on one or more remote computers."

Comment: What was said above. In other words, remove the `{...}` braces from around the path: `invoke-command -session $s -filepath C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoke-Command invocation of server script error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194488/invoke-command-invocation-of-server-script-error)

Comment: Yes - that describes why it's not working as written. So I guess the only way to run it on the remote computer (with the script stored there) is to use the share?

Comment: I would post it as answer but I'm not 100% sure it would work. If you need to "invoke" that remote script, in the script block of your `Invoke-Command`, try with `{ & 'c:\automatedtests\test.ps1 }`

Comment: @mklement0 the thing is, i'm not aware of what `test.ps1` is, if it's attempting to connect to a third host he would get the double-hop issue (which Tessellating noted)

Comment: @mklement0 - that does not work. Trying this:  invoke-command -computername 'us14-pacci04' -filepath { & 'C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1'} I get this error. Same with { .  'C:\AutomatedTests\test.ps1'} invoke-command : The value of the FilePath parameter must be a Windows PowerShell script file. Enter the path to a
file with a .ps1 file name extension and try the command again.

Comment: @Ben_G: Do not use `-FilePath` - use `-ScriptBlock` (or use the script block positionally), as now shown in Santiago's answer. As noted previously, `-FilePath` is for copying the _content_ of a script _from the caller_ to the remote computer, for execution there.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the script on the remote host using the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & 'c:\automatedtests\test.ps1'} -ComputerName RemoteComputer
```

Or the [dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { . 'c:\automatedtests\test.ps1'} -ComputerName RemoteComputer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$sess = New-PSSession...`  to connect to the remote machine, then `Copy-Item -ToSession $sess ...` to copy the file over to a folder on the remote machine, then `Invoke-Command -Session $sess ...` to run it on the remote machine.

(This saves you the double-hop problem of running a command on the remote machine which needs to connect out to a fileshare)