# What namespace do I need to use PowerShell in C# and where can I find it? System.Management.Automation?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to access PowerShell from within C# and it seems as though I need to reference the namespace System.Management.Automation and I can't find it anywhere I've searched my C: drive, google and my MSDN subscription (searching for "powershell SDK") and I can't find anything.

So my questions are:

1. Is this the namespace where I'll find the PowerShell object referenced in the codeblock below (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761613/why-cant-i-execute-remote-scripts-using-powershell-5-1/70762966#70762966))?
2. If not what namespace do I need and where can I find it?

   ```
   using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
   {

       PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

       string param1= "my param";
       string param2= "another param";
       string scriptPath = <path to script>;

       ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(scriptPath));

       ps.AddArgument(param1);
       ps.AddArgument(param2);

       ps.Invoke();
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, [System.Management.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) is the correct namespace.

Comment: So where can I find that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking which assembly/package you need to reference to be able to resolve `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` in your own project? Or are you asking about where to find documentation?

Comment: I'm asking which assembly/package you need to reference to be able to resolve System.Management.Automation.PowerShell in your own project. And where can I find this assembly/package. I've seen the docs. Can't find the assembly. Thought I just found it in NuGet, but that turned into a nightmare of dependencies that isn't working. I actually installed the NuGet package but I don't see it in my References and I can't instantiate any code based on it.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211358/how-to-automate-either-powershell-or-powershell-core-for-same-machine/58211901#58211901

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```